# Ruby map() for a single object

Tags: ruby, dictionary

I am looking for a way to 'map' a single item in Ruby.

I want to call this function and pass it a block, the object will be yielded to the block, and then the result of the block will be returned to the caller.  Exactly what map does, but for a single element.

The motivation is that sometimes you generate objects that are just used to construct something else.  The original object is then no longer needed.  It would be nice to just put the conversion into a block and eliminate the temporary.

As a contrived example, let's assume that I want to create an integer that represents the month/year combination.  For today's date, the code would look something like:

```
day = Date.today
month_number = day.year * 100 + day.month
```

I'd really like it if I could do something like:

```
month_number = Date.today.some_function { |d| d.year * 100 + d.month }
```

But I don't know what 'some_function' is (or if it even exists).

If there is a more Ruby way of handling something like this, I'm all ears.  I am aware of monkey patching classes, but I am looking to handle those cases that are a bit more transient.

Comment: [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) is so close but it doesn't return the value of the block...

Comment: Something like? m = lambda { |d| d.year * 100 + d.month }.call(Date.today)

Comment: See @jondavidjohn 's answer.  Built in and no proc binding overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Ruby 2.5 (end of 2017) and Ruby 2.6 there are new answers to this question, namely `yield_self` and `then`, respectively.

According to [the docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-yield_self), these methods *yield self to the block and return the result of the block*.

With your question's example

```rb
month_number = Date.today.then { |d| d.year * 100 + d.month }
```

`month_number` would be *202207* – as of the day of writing.

In newer Ruby Versions these methods were moved from `Object` [to `Kernel`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-then). They [seem to be identical](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/82add06f9cbe00ad611e99692d8d49b77159c601/kernel.rb#L120-L149); I've no idea why they were not aliased or sth like that, though.

Answer (score 22):

[**`instance_eval`**](http://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject/instance_eval) is what you're looking for.

```
month_number = Date.today.instance_eval { |d| d.year * 100 + d.month }
```

The `|d|` is also optional and `self` defaults to the object context.

This may satisfy your needs in a more compact way.

```
month_number = Date.today.instance_eval { year * 100 + month }
```

Comment: It looks like the |d| is optional as well (self will be the instance during the block execution).  So the following will work as well: Date.today.instance_eval {year * 100 + month}

Comment: On Rails, for `Object`-derived classes, you can also call `try` with a block without accepting an argument, and the block will be `instance_eval`’ed instead: 

`month_number = Date.today.try { year * 100 + month }`

Answer (score 20):

Using `instance_eval` as in `jondavidjohn`'s answer is one way to go, but it has overhead for reassigning `self`. Such feature was once [proposed in Ruby core](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6684#note-2), but was rejected and was withdrawn. Using the solution presented there by one of the Ruby developers knu (Akinori MUSHA), you could write like this:

```
month_number = Date.today.tap{|d| break d.year * 100 + d.month}
```

Using `tap`, the only extra thing you need to do is put `break` at the beginning of the block.

---

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 500000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report{n.times{Date.today.instance_eval{year * 100 + month}}}
  x.report{n.times{Date.today.instance_eval{|d| d.year * 100 + d.month}}}
  x.report{n.times{Date.today.tap{|d| break d.year * 100 + d.month}}}
end

       user     system      total        real
   2.130000   0.400000   2.530000 (  2.524296)
   2.120000   0.400000   2.520000 (  2.527134)
   1.410000   0.390000   1.800000 (  1.799213)
```

Comment: +1 for the answer most likely to be favored by the core team.  I'm still learning some of Ruby's ins and outs and the behavior of breaking from blocks is new to me.  In this case, I honestly find the behavior of the language discomfiting.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby's builtin [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) is close but it doesn't return the value of the block.

Here's an idea:

```
class Object
  def sap
    yield self
  end
end

eleven = 10.sap { |x| x + 1 } # => 11
month_number = Date.today.sap { |d| d.year * 100 + d.month } # => 201202
```

Comment: Why would you monkey patch if you didn't half to? see my answer below.

Comment: +1 for a nice, short syntax, but I think that @jondavidjohn 's use of instance_eval is more correct by virtue of being built in.

Comment: While `instance_eval` works comparably it also reveals the member variables of the target object, breaking the interface/implementation barrier.  This isn't so much a security concern as a chance to accidentally blow your foot off.  IMHO monkey patching is justified in this case.

Comment: It's better to implement with nil check of self. Then you can avoid some nil checks, so `2.smap { |x| x + 10 } => 12` or `nil.smap { |x| x + 10 } => nil`